# How does one find the circle in the following Apollonius-similar problem?

Tags: geometry, circles

Specifically, we are looking for the inner circle tangent to the two lines having center G, for which an outer circle centered on G with radius larger by T passes through point P.  This is similar to an Apollonius LLP-Problem.  Geometric solutions only please, no algebra!
[Problem depiction](https://i.stack.imgur.com/US9r0.png)

http://ggbtu.be/m1823693

Comment: You want to geometrically construct an inner circle (from given circle center G radius GP) with ring width/inside offset  T? Have you not done this already?

Comment: Exactly what are the "given"s here? The lines, the point $P$, and distance $T$?

Comment: Are you asking to construct a circle tangent to two intersecting lines and to the circle center $P$ radius $T$?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that two lines, point P and distance T are given. Then the stated problem is equivalent to the Apollonius CLL-problem, where the circle has center P and radius T and must be touched from the outside. This problem can then be reduced to the Apollonius LLP-problem by shifting the lines by distance T and using the original point P.